# Hive Select Into

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a database people in hive. It's schema is as follows:

```
name string,
dob_date int,
dob_month int,
dob_year int.
```

I have successfully loaded data from a file into the database.
Now I want to have people having `dob_year=1990` into a new table.
The following code doesn't work :

```
Select * into people1990 from people where dob_year=1990;
```

Comment: table name should be people i think u gave it wrong

Comment: create table people1990 as select * from people where dob_year=1990 should work

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use  [create table tablename as](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable) in Hive.

example:

```
create table people1990 as select * from people where dob_year=1990
```